# Visual Studio 2010 Editor does not refresh/display right on an extended secondary monitor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, editor, refresh

I am using Visual Studio 2010.  I have a notebook and extend my desktop area to a secondary monitor.  Because the secondary monitor is a lot bigger, I use it most of the time when developing codes.  I notice that the visual studio editor has some screen refresh/display issue on the secondary monitor.  The text are overlapping each other.  This does not happen on the primary monitor.  Is there something that I can do to compensate this?  Thanks very much.

I should have looked further.  I found this link
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/575376/visual-studio-2010-code-editor-problems
It is a known issue in Microsoft.  They do provide a work around way.  Basically, turn off the "Visual Experience".

Comment: That worked perfectly. I've been fighting visual studio for at least a week, byt today was the worst. I'm glad i found this.